# IntelliJ displays UPPERCASE on Run Configuration section

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-14, intellij-15

In my Java apps, I realized that IntelliJ displays UPPERCASE on Run Configuration section as shown below. I thought it may be caused by Material Theme or Atom Icon plugins, but after disabling Atom Icon and selecting default Dracula Theme, it still the same (I am not sure maybe it is not related for these 2 plugins). Any idea to fix it and display as CamelCase?

[image]

Comment: And you're sure the run config isn't just named that way? Works perfectly fine for me, but then I never installed any themes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable / disable uppercase buttons e.g. Run configuration, etc:

```
Settings > Material Theme UI > Settings > Components > Uppercase buttons
```